# How do i update a specific render without having to reload the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

F represents the length of the favorites state and W represents the length of the watchedmovies state.

This is how I display them in my Navigation component :

({`F-${totalFavorites}, W-${totalWatched}`}) 
In my App.js this is how I pass it :

totalFavorites={this.state.favorites.length}
totalWatched={this.state.moviesWatched.length}
The problem I have with is this is that when you press the clear button the totalFavorites doesn't update automatically, you have to refresh the page for it to show F-0.

This is my clear function which is on the onClick of my button :

```
clearMovies = () => {
this.setState({ sortedFavorites: "" });
localStorage.setItem("favorites", "");
};
```

Ignore that I haven't done it for WatchedMovies. So sortedFavorites is like a duplicate for favorites.

How would you make it so that when you press the clear button, the totalFavorites is updated without having to reload the page?

Here's the code for submenu.js : https://gist.github.com/justgoof9/d77645b270e323b31d04bd13779538a6

Comment: Just a guess, it looks like you would need to call some prop in the parent of `Dashboard` to update the `totalFavorites` prop from there)

Comment: @kingdaro the thing is that totalFavorites updates but only when you refresh the page. I want it to update without having to refresh the page.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. The value `totalFavorites`, whatever state that's depending on, that state needs to be updated directly. Doing so through local storage won't work, because React doesn't listen to localStorage updates, only state updates done through `setState`